# Why do we need to have exactly 3690 rep to be eligible for nomination? Why not 3.5K or 4K?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I was reading how this year's election went and decided to read up on the [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) needed to be a Mod when I noticed on the side bar,

> > ...any community member in good standing with more than **3,690** reputation may nominate themselves...

Which I though is quite particular, for as far as I know reaching 3,690 rep doesn't entitle you to any special privileges or badges or anything else for that matter. So why does the rep requirement need to be precisely *3,690*<sup>1</sup>? Why not round it down to 3.5K, or up to 4K<sup>2</sup>?

---

<sup>1 As it currently stands there are [626](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205025#messages) users eligible for nomination, so it's not like the rep limit is in place to restrict the possible number of candidates to a nicely rounded number...</sup>

<sup>2 For the sake of statistics I thought I may as well include these. Rep limit 3.5K: [636](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205026#messages) candidates. Rep limit 4K: [612](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205028#messages) candidates. The rep limit would have to be at 10,050 to have [500](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205036#messages) candidates and without any rep limit there would be [712](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205044#messages) candidates</sup>

Comment: In February 2014 the number of candidates eligible would have been different (lower), but yeah, the number looks odd.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would that've been because the rep requirement was raised or was that just due to users having less rep & badges?

Comment: Nicely rounded numbers are overrated. I'd be just as happy if the levels on SO were based solely on powers of two, or perfect squares.

Comment: Regarding 1: KV 626 is Mozart's requiem. I wouldn't blame SE for assigning meaning to that number ;)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

In fact, the reputation limit is exactly 3k for Stack Overflow (only 2k on other sites)—a nice round number that a normal person can be proud of!

The deal is that you're reading the nomination page after 30 nominees were submitted. In that case, the system only allows you to nominate yourself if you have at least the same reputation score as the nominee with the lowest reputation score. In other words, you have/had to beat [hichris123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581872/hichris123), with his current reputation of 3,690.

<sup>(Source: [Trilogy 2011 Elections Begin](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/trilogy-2011-elections-begin/))</sup>

Comment: This appears to vary by site, for example in the last [Electrical Engineering election](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/3) there was a nominee with under 2k rep and the page lists 300 as the requirement.

Comment: Yes, it is very likely different for the smaller sites with a lot fewer users. Fortunately, this is now the Stack Overflow specific Meta, so I don't have to know about that!

Comment: @user0000000 When were *those* days? Clearly before my time. And I've been around for 4 years or so.

Comment: So if the 30 most reputed nominate themselves, nobody can get there anymore?

Comment: @user189 In theory, correct. In practice, that won't happen. Many of the top users are not interested in becoming moderators, it'd certainly take a lot of time away from their answering questions. ;-)

Comment: Not necessarily. Someone could come swooping in with a big burst of rep and overtake the lower few nominees. If I had about 170k extra rep, I'd be tempted to give it try at the next election just to see what would happen.

Comment: `In theory, correct. In practice, that won't happen.` If I had a nickel for every time I said that...

Comment: Remember that "In theory, theory and practice are the same.  In practice, theory and practice differ."

Comment: Good point - in theory.

Comment: Note: the nomination page is tracking with live data even if the election has ended. It's now showing 10105, the same as hichris123's current reputation.