# Why is the reputation requirement 3000 in the moderator election nomination phase?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Why is **3000** reputation the requirement in the moderator election nomination phase, even though **20000** is the threshold for [**trusted user**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)?

I checked this on the [2015 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) page, the right sidebar has:

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than 3,000 reputation may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.

Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Actually a very good question... my guess is that the "trusted user" label is meaningless in the context of diamond moderation, or at the very least it means something entirely different, since it is a rep-based privilege.

Comment: It will [increase somewhat](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261896/why-do-we-need-to-have-exactly-3690-rep-to-be-eligible-for-nomination-why-not-3?rq=1) when sufficiently many candidates have volunteered themselves (to match the least-reputed candidate).

Comment: I believe that the same reasons for: "For the Stack Overflow election, an eligible candidate for the election must have all of the following badges:

    Civic Duty
    Strunk & White
    Deputy
    Convention
". I think is a mechanisms to weed out people that wouldn't use effectively the tools to their disposition.

Comment: If badges is considers then i have 3 badges out of 4 even not have 3000 reputation. If i get 1 more badges( which doesn't effect reputation) then i can also elegiacal even  don't have 3000 reputation.

Comment: Cuz we hate noobs.

Comment: No, I think you need the four badges **and** the 3000 reputation to be eligible.

Comment: We have elected moderators without huge reputation. Anna Lear was elected in the [2011 election](http://stackoverflow.com/election/2), at the time I believe she had less than 10k reputation. This is a good example of someone that didn't have a whole lot of reputation on the site, but was well suited for the moderator position.

Comment: Tim Post was also barely over 10k when he was elected.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

On most sites, the minimum reputation to nominate is a paltry **300 (Three Hundred)** points. Just enough to have spent a bit of time on the site and have earned a few privileges.

When we tried this on Stack Overflow, the results were... Chaotic. A *lot* of nominations were posted from folks with *no* hope of being elected, along with joke nominations and nominations from folks who... kinda just found themselves in the wrong place.

This wasn't exactly conducive to civil discussion and careful review of candidates' qualifications.

So, we raised the minimum reputation to 3000, and added a handful of badges to the base requirements. Note that these requirements are still far, far below the qualifications generally held by the folks who actually get elected - that's ok! Better to err on the side of allowing some underqualified candidates than excluding potentially-excellent moderator.

Finally, it's worth noting that the base reputation threshold *isn't static* during the election: to reduce voter fatigue, only 30 candidates can progress to the primary phase, and those 30 are chosen from the pool of candidates based on reputation: so once 30 candidates have joined the election, the reputation requirement you see in the sidebar will increase to the reputation of the 30th candidate by reputation.

Comment: Can we do something similar for the "Famous Question" badge on stackoverflow? http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold