# Reputation threshold for the first election

Tags: support, reputation, moderator-election

I just noticed that in the [first SO moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=nomination) the minimum reputation was set to 65,882.

> [image: 65882 reputation]

All following elections have the threshold set to 3,000. What's the source of that weird (65882) value?

Comment: Possible dupe/related: [Why do we need to have exactly 3690 rep to be eligible for nomination? Why not 3.5K or 4K?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261896/2821954): lowest rep from top 30 candidates, and it's using the live data, not the rep at that time.